# auto start an ios app

Tags: ios, ipad, jailbreak, ssh, startup

I want an app(specifically Ip Messanger for iOs) to start on startup in my ipad ios 7.1.1. I saw [this](https://github.com/rpetrich/untrackerd/blob/master/layout/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.rpetrich.untrackerd.plist) 3 years old source in github and write the following .plist file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">

<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.mac.eijimiwa.ipmessenger</string>

    <key>Program</key>
    <string>/var/mobile/Applications/268983D6-12F9-45B5-ABF4-5B5F3D1C5E90/IP\ Messenger\ for\ iOS.app/IP\ Messenger\ for\ iOS</string>

    <key>OnDemand</key>
    </false>

</dict>

</plist>
```

I cannot be sure if I made a mistake or the plist format is no longer supported by ios v7.1.1. Can anyone point me what I shall correct or other auto-start options?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't run GUI apps by running the binary like that.

Install [**open**](http://moreinfo.thebigboss.org/moreinfo/depiction.php?file=openData) from Cydia, then use `open bundleid`:

```
<key>ProgramArguments</key>
<array>
    <string>open</string>
    <string>com.app.bundleid</string>
</array>
```

Comment: I know the 'open' tool. But can you tell me how I can I use it to start an app at start time?

Comment: @Bere Added example. Remove your invalid *Program* key and replace it with the above, once you've installed open.

Comment: thanks. one question... where shall I put the .plist file? In /Library/LaunchDaemons or /Library/LaunchAgents?

Comment: @Bere Either should work I think (try both); not quite sure how iOS handles it as there's no login and don't have my device to hand right now to test.

Comment: Thank you @George very much. I put the plist file in /Library/LaunchDeamons/ (it didn't work in /Library/LaunchAgents) and added the following configuration    `<key>KeepAlive</key><dict><key>SuccessfulExit</key><false/></dict>` to make start and keep running it until normal exit.